# Preposition, Which form is correct?

Tags: prepositions, pronouns

From the Collins Dictionary's definition of *[take](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/take)*

> If a person, vehicle, or path takes someone somewhere, they transport or lead them there.

or

> If a person, vehicle, or path takes someone **to** somewhere, they transport or lead them there.

Comment: Native speakers wouldn't normally say something like *The car led us to our destination*. Normally only something ***sentient, capable of intentionality*** can do things like that - but metaphorically, something like a path or road can *lead [someone] somewhere* simply by virtue of the fact that *if you follow that route*, you will end up at that destination. In your exact context, the presence or absence of the preposition ***to*** is optional, and has no real significance. But we'd always include it in *The path led **to** his house*, and never include it in *He led her home*.

Comment: It is clear, and which one is correct?

> someone **to** somewhere
 
or 

> someone somewhere    @FumbleFingers

Comment: Are you taking a trip somewhere? Without **to**

Comment: I don't know exactly how to explain what syntactic principle is involved here. I *think* it might be that ***some*** is a kind of "determiner", which somehow *(optionally)* allows us not to bother with a preposition after ***to lead*** (or other verbs which can have a similar meaning, such as ***take***). Thus in contexts like*He took me [to] somewhere nice for a candlelit dinner* it's entirely a stylistic choice whether to include ***to*** or not. But we can't do that if we particularise "somewhere nice" to a specific place - you *must* include it in, say, *He took me **to** McDonald's.*

Answer (score 1):

This is a good observation. Substitute a person or thing for *someone* and a location for *somewhere*, and the preposition would certainly be expected:

> A ferry takes workers to and from the island.
>
> The Alaska Highway takes you toward Beaver Creek.
>
> She took the children into their house.

This is not, however, something special about *[take](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/take)*; rather, the trick is that *somewhere* is not used an indefinite pronoun here. Its most common usage is adverbial (e.g. [MMD](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/somewhere), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/somewhere), [MW](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/somewhere)), indicating moving to or being in or at some unspecified or unknown location. Try replacing *somewhere* with another adverb of place to make better sense of it:

> A ferry takes workers offshore.
>
> The Alaska Highway takes you eastward.
>
> She took the children home.

*Anywhere*, *elsewhere*, *everywhere*, *nowhere*, and *someplace* (and *anyplace* and *everyplace*, which are less common and mostly found in North American English) are also primarily adverbs, although they can be used as pronouns.

Some prepositions can also act as adverbs of place, thus how you would classify it would depend on whether or not there is an object:

> My boss is taking me around tomorrow.
>   My boss is taking me around the factory tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

'Somewhere' and 'someplace' are pronouns that are typically used adverbially, where the preposition can be assumed (causing many to simply call them adverbs).

"He went [to] somewhere."  (adverb)

"He is [at] somewhere."  (adverb)

"He came from somewhere."  ('somewhere' is a pronoun, and 'from somewhere' is an adverbial phrase)